# Storyboard applied on dummy UIElement stops running randomly

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, storyboard, dependency-properties

I would like to show my problem first before showing my code at the end. 
I want to create an attached property used on `AnimationTimeline` to help animate non-animatable properties (including all non-DependencyProperties). The idea here is hook up the input `TargetProperty` and animate a property (of the same type) of a dummy UIElement. This dummy UIElement exposes an event called `ValueChanged` so that we can hook up and update the non-animatable property of the actual object there.

More specifically, I would like to animate the `Position` property of a `MediaElement`. I want to make it play backwards and repeatedly. It runs fairly smoothly even for dozens of cycles (if you just watch it for such as ten cycles, you will be deceived and may think: ah! everything is OK). Yes but after that it may stop running. I don't have any clue on why it could happen. The only thought  at first was maybe my dummy object is destroyed by GC somehow but I even tried keeping its reference in a static collection but the problem still occurred.

Here is my code:

**Code**:

```
//Currently this supports only Double and Int32 animations
public class Dummy<T> : UIElement
{
    public Dummy(){
        //I found myself that this is very important to make it work 
        //at least for dozens of cycles, otherwise it just stops running 
        //when the first cycle has not been done.
        //Still don't understand why this is needed.
        Application.Current.MainWindow.RegisterName("_" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", ""), this);
    }
    public T Data { get; set; }        
    public event DummyValueChangedEventHandler ValueChanged;
    protected void OnValueChanged(DummyValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var handler = ValueChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, e);
    }
    public DependencyProperty GetDependencyPropertyOfType(Type type)
    {            
        if (typeof(double).IsAssignableFrom(type)) return DoubleProperty;
        else if (typeof(int).IsAssignableFrom(type)) return Int32Property;
        return null;
    }
    #region DependencyProperties
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DoubleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Double", typeof(double), typeof(Dummy<T>), new PropertyMetadata(propertyChangedHandler));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty Int32Property =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Int32", typeof(int), typeof(Dummy<T>), new PropertyMetadata(propertyChangedHandler));
    #endregion       
    #region properties changed handlers
    private static void propertyChangedHandler(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dummy = o as Dummy<T>;
        dummy.OnValueChanged(new DummyValueChangedEventArgs(e.NewValue));
    }
    #endregion
    public delegate void DummyValueChangedEventHandler(object sender, DummyValueChangedEventArgs e);
    public class DummyValueChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public object Value { get; private set; }
        public DummyValueChangedEventArgs(object value)
        {
            Value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

The `DummyData` used for this demo:

```
struct DummyData
{
    public Action<object> ValueSetter { get; set; }
    public IValueConverter Converter { get; set; }
    public DummyData(Action<object> valueSetter, IValueConverter converter = null)
        : this()
    {
        ValueSetter = valueSetter;
        Converter = converter;
    }        
}
```

Here is an extension for `PropertyPath`, the actual code is more complicated because it supports complex path, but in this case the path is just simple (like `Position`) so this code is enough to test the whole code:

```
public static class PropertyPathExtension {
     public static Action<object> GetSetter(this PropertyPath current, object target) {
          var propInfo = target.GetType().GetProperty(current.Path);
          if(propInfo != null){
             return (o) => propInfo.SetValue(target, o, null);
          }
          return null;
     }
}
```

Because `Position` is a `TimeSpan`, but I use a `DoubleAnimation` to animate it, so I need a Converter like this to convert `double` (representing milliseconds) to `TimeSpan`:

```
public class MillisecondsToTimeSpanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new TimeSpan((long)((double)value * TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond)); 
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Here is another class wrapping the `PropertyPath` and a converter:

```
public class PropertyWithConverter : MarkupExtension
{
    public PropertyPath Path { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// The Converter used to convert the input value before setting for the property.
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public IValueConverter Converter { get; set; }
    public PropertyWithConverter(PropertyPath path)
    {
        Path = path;
    }
    public PropertyWithConverter(string path)
    {
        Path = new PropertyPath(path);
    }
    public PropertyWithConverter(PropertyPath path, IValueConverter converter){
        Path = path;
        Converter = converter;
    }
    public PropertyWithConverter(string path, IValueConverter converter)
    {
        Path = new PropertyPath(path);
        Converter = converter;
    }
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) {
        return new PropertyWithConverter(Path, Converter);
    }
}
```

Finally the `StoryboardX` acting as the owner of some useful attached properties I'm creating:

```
public class StoryboardX {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TargetPropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("TargetProperty", typeof(PropertyWithConverter), typeof(StoryboardX), new PropertyMetadata(targetPropertyChanged));

    public static PropertyWithConverter GetTargetProperty(DependencyObject o)
    {
        return o.GetValue(TargetPropertyProperty) as PropertyWithConverter;
    }
    public static void SetTargetProperty(DependencyObject o, PropertyWithConverter path)
    {
        o.SetValue(TargetPropertyProperty, path);
    }
    static private void targetPropertyChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var anim = o as AnimationTimeline;
        var target = Storyboard.GetTarget(o);
        if (!(target is MediaElement)) return;
        var prop = StoryboardX.GetTargetProperty(o);

        var dummy = new Dummy<DummyData>() {                 
            Data = new DummyData(prop.Path.GetSetter(target), prop.Converter)
        };
        //hook up this to update the actual property
        dummy.ValueChanged += dummyValueChanged;            
        var dp = dummy.GetDependencyPropertyOfType(anim.TargetPropertyType);
        if (dp != null)
        {
            //update this to make Storyboard animate the dummy instead.
            Storyboard.SetTarget(o, dummy);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(o, new PropertyPath(dp.Name));
        }            
    }
    static private void dummyValueChanged(object sender, Dummy<DummyData>.DummyValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dummy = sender as Dummy<DummyData>;
        var vl = e.Value;
        if (dummy.Data.Converter != null)
            vl = dummy.Data.Converter.Convert(vl, typeof(TimeSpan), null, null);

        dummy.Data.ValueSetter(vl);
    }

}
```

**XAML**:

Currently `StoryboardX` can hook up only `Target` directly using `Storyboard.GetTarget`, not able to derive from `TargetName` (using `Storyboard.GetTargetName`), so I used `{x:Reference}` to set `MediaElement` for target:

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <local:MillisecondsToTimeSpanConverter x:Key="cv"/>
</Grid.Resources>
<MediaElement Name="player" 
                  Source="e:\myVideoPath.mp4" LoadedBehavior="Pause" 
              ScrubbingEnabled="True"/>
<Grid.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation From="21000" To="0" Duration="00:00:21" 
                                     Storyboard.Target="{x:Reference player}" RepeatBehavior="Forever" 
                         local:StoryboardX.TargetProperty="{local:PropertyWithConverter Position, Converter={StaticResource cv}}"/>

                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
</Grid.Triggers>
```

Also note that the `From` and `To` should be set to some values (in milliseconds) in range of the Duration of the media clip, you should know this beforehand using some actual  player or windows explorer. The code I provided here is some kind of beginning demo.

I would like to get some suggestion from you because I've run out of ideas solving this tricky problem (it runs smoothly for dozens of cycles but then may stop running randomly). As I said, if you're interested in, please test the code long enough, it may run smoothly for cycles but stop running then randomly.

Also as I commented in the `Dummy` constructor, this shows that it's important to make it run fairly normally, you can try commenting it out and see how it stops running shortly:

```
Application.Current.MainWindow.RegisterName("_" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", ""), this);
```

So that may be a point solving problem, I added that line by guessing what's possibly wrong and it at least helps running the animation longer.

Also the test clip should be longer than 10 seconds, because I tested a clip of 10 seconds and it worked OK but I've tested many clips of more than 10 seconds and none of them worked.

Thank you all for your help.

**Edit**:
I've found out that if adding the dummy `UIElement` to the visual tree, it seems to work OK. By looking at the source code of `UIElementCollection`, I saw some methods called there: *AddLogicalChild, VisualCollection.Add and _visualParent.InvalidateMeasure*. 
So I've tried calling `InvalidateMeasure` on the `UIElement` (but did not add it to the visual tree this time) and looks like it also almost works OK. I've tried it many times, let it run for hours and everything seems OK but somehow (in another time running the app) it was just failed once (a very rare time of failing). At least it works better now in sense of not stopping too soon and sometimes totally working. So this problem is really tricky. It's totally confusing about the relationship between animating a `DependencyProperty` (which any `DependencyObject` can have) and the UIElement's layout (I mean the involvement of `InvalidateMeasure` call).

Comment: Your converter seems unnecessarily complicated. Are you sure that's not the problem? What wrong with a simple  `return new TimeSpan((double)value * TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond);` ?

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer yes, I can simply declare a class having just one method called `Convert` receiving just one value of input type and returning a value of output type. It however does not matter here, I mean the actual problem I'm encountering.

Comment: Just wondered if buggy converter was causing animation to stall due to wrong values being spat out.

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer I don't think the converter could cause an issue here, think about this: The animation has a mission of animating a `Double`, while the converter just convert that `Double` to a `TimeSpan` and set for `Position`. If it matters, an invalid value may be set for `Position` but what exactly it is when `To` is `0` (TimeSpan.Zero) and `From` is some value corresponding to  some middle point of the media clip?, I mean there won't be an invalid value for `Position` here.